# Universal binaries for OpenCL

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu

I have 2 computers, one with Raden R9 290x, and Radeon R7 250 in another. The following discussion focuses only on AMD graphics cards. On both machines the same driver installed. I wrote OpenCL kernel, compile it into a binary and use `clCreateProgramWithBinary`. But I was faced with the following challenges:

Compiled binaries for these two devices are different: for R7 binary weighs ~ 500KB, and for R9 ~ 1.5MB.

I have no problem when using the binary on the device for which it was compiled, everything happens instantly. But if I try to run the binary for R7 at R9, then `clBuildProgram` executed a very long time (~ 1 min.), And contrary (binary from R9 load to R7) `clBuildProgram` - causes access violation.

I need to get the binary that will run on all of AMD's graphics cards, support OpenCL. How to compile OpenCL kernel that it would work properly on all devices?

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov Thank you for your reply. Now I try to use SPIR. I compiled .spir file by Intel OpenCL Code Builder and load it like a binary. It works, but I get a lag during the clBuildProgram. Compiling OpenCL source code takes ~14s, with SPIR it takes 8s. This is payback for compatibility?

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov As I can see, the main aim of SPIR is hide source code. The need to compile the source code still there. My main aim is avoid lag of source code compilation.

Comment: R9 is a different and newer arquitecture. The binaries are definitely not going to be compatible. Unless as mentioned, you use SPIR. However it still forces you go to trough the compilation step. Why the R7 binary works on R9 after 1min compilation, is a mistery.

Comment: @DmitriBudnikov Huh, but [intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-spir-for-fun-and-profit-with-intel-opencl-code-builder) thinks differently - "The main goal of SPIR was to enable application developers to avoid shipping their kernels in a source form, while maintaining portability between vendors and devices." But it's offtop. My kernel contains ~3k lines, and I think that compilation really takes that time. In my case, I write DLL which includes binary in resources, so I have no way to cache it. I think I should try to separate the kernel now it contains independent parts.

Comment: @DarkZeros I think you are mistaken. I'm sure it's possible. Look at oclHashcat. They distribute binaries that work for all (?) AMD cards.